# Music Playing When Cursor Hovers

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, hover

I was able to get music to play when the cursor hovered over an image. I only did it for one image. Today, I tried putting in another image with a different song. Did not work - the second image plays the same song as the first image even though I put different tracks. Here is my code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hovermusic.css">
</head>


<body>

<script src="hovermusic.js"> </script>

<audio id="hoversound" src="LanaSummertimeSadness.mp3"></audio>
<button onmouseover="document.getElementById('hoversound').play()" onmouseout="document.getElementById('hoversound').pause()"><h1 class="handbags"> <center> Handbag Edition </h1> 
</center>

<h3 class="chloe"> <center> Bags </center> </h3>

<div class="handbags">
    <center>
        <table style="height:100">

                <td> <a href="http://www.a-land.co.kr/shop/main/index.php"> <img src="http://i1.wp.com/www.cachetdechloe.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/DSC_0092.jpg?resize=600%2C399" title="Backpack with Patches" 

                     <figcaption>
                        <center>First Day of School</center>
                    </figcaption></button>


                    </a> </td> </center> </div> 


<audio id="hovermusic" src="BlueJeansPreview.wav"></audio>



<div class="photo2">
    <center>
        <table style="height:100">

                <td onmouseover="document.getElementById('hovermusic').play()" onmouseout="document.getElementById('hovermusic').pause()">
 <a href="http://www.cachetdechloe.com"> <img src="http://i1.wp.com/www.cachetdechloe.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/DSC_0175.jpg" title="Gold For the Win" 

                     <figcaption>
                        <center>HK Summer 2015</center>
                    </figcaption></button>


                    </a> </td> </center> </div> 
                    </body>
```

Comment: Your html looks broken. Neither table is closed and the second is created directly after closing your first td, without creating another td. Can you try fixing the tables and see if it works? You also have tables inside of your buttons. It looks completely invalid.

Comment: Can you put some css which is connected to the audio (if it is).

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your HTML is a little messy and it's difficult to know exactly what's happening without seeing the css.

I'd suggest not using tables, and using jquery to speed things up a little. Here's some example code:

https://jsfiddle.net/amq2w00g/

Here is the javascript code, which is nothing too complicated:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".audio-box").mouseover(function(){
       var thisAudio = $(this).find("audio");
       thisAudio[0].play();
    });

});
```

If you need some more help doing this then please comment.